# Please help on The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, console

the code was working for over a year and all of a sudden it is throwing the error message "The given path's format is not supported."

```
     filepath = "C:\\\\FaxServer\\\\InBox\\\\1820200525_0 10:34 AM.pdf"
     if (!File.Exists(filePath))
     {
            FileStream Stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter BinaryStream = new BinaryWriter(Stream);
            BinaryStream.Write(attachment.Body);
            BinaryStream.Close();
         }
```

Comment: You have too many backwards slashes. Also, with spaces, as you have them, you probably need surrounding quotes.

Comment: Use [verbatim character @](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) instead to introduce a literal string. _@"C:\FaxServer\InBox\1820200525_0 10:34 AM.pdf";_

Comment: you should try `filepath = @"C:\FaxServer\InBox\1820200525_0 10:34 AM.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

Give normal file path but use `@` before string. `filepath =@"C:\FaxServer\InBox\1820200525_0 10:34 AM.pdf"` should be good.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, I am actually doing this instead string filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\FaxServer\\InBox\\", "1820200525_0 10:34 AM.pdf");